# Ruby on Rails available, unavailable and onloan state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

for my Library System in Rails 4 I want to show on the book sites if the displayed book is available, onloan or unavailable.

I'm not sure how to implement it. Is it possible to use a similar solution like the isAdmin state (if I use booleans only I can't really use the onloan function I want - showing the date on which the book is due to return).

In the rails tutorial I used something like this:

```
 if user.activated?
        log_in user
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
        redirect_back_or user
      else
        message  = "Account not activated. "
        message += "Check your email for the activation link."
        flash[:warning] = message
        redirect_to root_url
      end
```

And I was wondering if I'm on the right track with this.

Thanks in advance :)

Chrizzly

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant to provide answers to specific programming questions, like "I tried X and expected Y, but I got Z. Here's the code I used." Your question, on the other hand, concerns a design issue, which is out of scope. That said, take a look at [this article](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2012/10/10/booleans-are-baaaaaaaaaad/) on managing states with booleans. Consider implementing a "book_status_id" column referencing a "book_statuses" table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common question in web app design and I see roughly 3 ways to approach it:

1. **A single `status` string column** on your Book model (or whatever). For each record, this field contains either `"available"`, `"unavailable"`, or `"onloan"`. The model should use a `validates_inclusion_of` statement to ensure the value is always one of the accepted values. This is the most "manual" approach, the most wasteful of space (which matters if you have more than a few million records), and arguably poor practice though it's also my favorite by virtue of its simplicity.
2. **A `status` field that's either a key to a separate table of values, or an `enum` type** (a recently introduced concept that's meant for this specific situation). See [this article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/whats-new-in-edge-rails-active-record-enum) for a rundown of how `enum`s work. Personally I have yet to run into a situation that caused me to wish I'd taken this approach; simple strings are straightforward enough to set up.
3. **A separate `boolean` flag for each possible status**. If there's any chance in the world that these statuses may overlap (ie. is it *ever* possible for a record to be both onloan and unavailable?), then consider just setting up a separate boolean field for each possible status. This can complicate logic during updates (ie. you have to remember to turn on the new status and also turn off the old status), but this can be your only responsible option if you anticipate that statuses can have "complicated relationships". It's more mental complexity to set up and maintain, but I've used this a number of times (perhaps 20% of the time I'm planning out a status field) and I've never come to regret it later on.

Here I've just talked about database storage approach, I haven't even talked about your application logic -- but I think the code kind of flows from the database structure. So consider each of the above three, consider what kinds of code you could write with each (eg. what would that controller action look like, if you had a string field vs. if you had multiple boolean columns?) and in the end the decision will probably come down to what the code looks and feels like for each approach.

Good luck!